# Function approximation: why does using increasingly higher order approximating polynomials not lead to convergent approximation schemes in general?

Tags: numerical-analysis

Given some equally spaced data for a function on an interval, we can use line segments (pictured below), quadratic functions, various cubic schemes, and increasingly higher order polynomials to approximate the function using this equally spaced data.

[image]

For the linear scheme I show as an example in the figure above, as $h \rightarrow 0$, the approximation error also approaches zero, so we say the scheme is "convergent".

In general though, using increasingly higher order polynomials as approximations on the equally spaced intervals *does not* guarantee convergence. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolation_error) has an explanation that says that $h^{n+1}f^{(n+1)}(\xi)$ may not approach zero as $h$ approaches zero, if $f^{(n+1)}(\xi)$ dominates. Can you show this in a problematic case using pictures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is commonly called "Runge's phenomenon", and is similar to Gibbs' phenomenon, which is encountered when using Fourier series to approximate a function. The Wikipedia pages [convergence of polynomial approximation schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Convergence_properties), and on [Runge's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) have a clear discussion, along with a picture to show the phenomenon in action:

[image]

> **Caption from Wikipedia** (emphasis mine): The **red** curve is the Runge function.
>   The **blue** curve is a 5th-order interpolating polynomial (using six equally spaced interpolating points).
>   The **green** curve is a 9th-order interpolating polynomial (using ten equally spaced interpolating points).
>   At the interpolating points, the error between the function and the interpolating polynomial is (by definition) zero. Between the interpolating points (especially in the region close to the endpoints 1 and −1), the error between the function and the interpolating polynomial gets worse for higher-order polynomials.

Comment: To minimize Runge's phenomena we typically don't use uniformly spaced points, but rather cosine spacing known as the [Chebyshev Nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes)